# Do I need to include all DB Tables in my Entity Data Model? (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I model my database 1st using DB Designer Fork, complete with keys, indices and relationships. I then make an SQL Create script for this then run it in MySql 5.5 (sometimes MS Sql).

Then I create an ASP.NET/c# website in VS2010. This is my new software and I intend to use Entity Data Model (the one that uses .edmx files) for my new projects.

I can actually "drag-and-drop" my existing db tables in the edmx and it comes complete with relationships and all. But do I really want/need to do this, knowing that I need to create new entities for joined tables?

BACKGROUND: I'm more comfortable with SQL queries and Database ER diagrams than "Application Class Diagrams" but I want to use this Entity Data Model because I believe it will save me a lot of time and hassle managing hundreds of queries like how I used to do things.

Answer (score 0):

There is not required to include all the tables in the selected database. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716703.aspx) for clarification.

But I suggest that if you are creating a new project then use EF Code First model.